# Issue displaying travel time in input form result - need assistance

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Can someone please help me understand why my code to display the travel time is not appearing in the input form result, even though the distance value is displayed? The issue is that the waktu_tempuh part does not show up. Is there a solution to this problem? I've been stuck for 2 weeks because of this issue :(

here my code :

```js
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Waktu Tempuh</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="travelTime" name="waktu_tempuh" placeholder="Hasil Waktu Tempuh" readonly>
            </div>

function updatePath() {
            var startLatitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('startLatitude').value);
            var startLongitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('startLongitude').value);
            var endLatitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('endLatitude').value);
            var endLongitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('endLongitude').value);
            var shipSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shipSpeed').value);

            // Validasi kecepatan kapal
            if (isNaN(shipSpeed) || shipSpeed <= 0 || shipSpeed > 50) {
                alert("Mohon masukkan kecepatan kapal yang valid antara 1 dan 50 knot.");
                return;
            }

            var startPoint = [startLatitude, startLongitude];
            var endPoint = [endLatitude, endLongitude];

            if (curve1) {
                map.removeLayer(curve1);
            }

            curve1 = L.pathCurve(startPoint, endPoint).addTo(map);

            var halfwayPoint = L.latLng(
                (startPoint[0] + endPoint[0]) / 2,
                (startPoint[1] + endPoint[1]) / 2
            );

            addWaypointOnCurve(curve1, halfwayPoint);

            var route = getRoute(startPoint, endPoint);
            routeData = route; // Menyimpan data rute ke variabel global
            var distance = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < route.length; i++) {
                var latlng1 = [route[i - 1].x - 90, route[i - 1].y - 360];
                var latlng2 = [route[i].x - 90, route[i].y - 360];
                distance += calculateDistance(latlng1, latlng2);
            }
            var distanceInKm = distance / 1000;
            document.getElementById('travelDistance').value = distanceInKm.toFixed(2);
            var travelTime = calculateTravelTime(distanceInKm, shipSpeed);
            document.getElementById('travelTime').value = travelTime.toFixed(2);
            updateShipPosition(route, shipMarker, shipSpeed);
        }
```

I attempted to create a code to display the travel time in an input form result. I expected both the distance and waktu_tempuh values to appear, but only the distance is showing up. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't been able to resolve this issue in the past two weeks. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.